# sbt "runMain com.... arg1" calls `packageBin`

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there any reason why `sbt "runMain com.... arg1"` would call the `packageBin` task ?

Is there a way to disable it to speed up development cycle ?

Edit:

```
> inspect runMain
...
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  Compile / bgJobService
[info]  Compile / bgRunMain
...
```

Recording of the `runMain ....`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not think `packageBin`  should be a dependency of `runMain` out-of-the-box, however there is nothing preventing someone explicitly wiring it like so

```
Compile / runMain := {
  (Compile / packageBin).value    // this make runMain depend on packageBin
  (Compile / runMain).evaluated
}
```

Perhaps investigate `build.sbt` if you can find a similar dependency and simply remove `(Compile / packageBin).value` part. You could also investigate dependencies of tasks with

```
inspect runMain
```

There should be a `Dependencies` section that might looks like so

```
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  Compile / bgJobService
[info]  Compile / bgRunMain
[info]  Compile / packageBin
```

Comment: I think that started when I installed `sbt-assembly` , is there a way to disable it ? So when I run `runMain` is it faster ?

Comment: I added a recording of the build log. So you can see the steps

Comment: @Wonay Please post your `build.sbt`

Comment: My build.sbt really have nothing special. it is just libraryDependencies and thats it. The only "fancy" thing installed is `sbt-assembly`

Comment: I tried removing `sbt-assembly` and the behavior is the same